# AFNetworking CFData Leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, afnetworking

I am having a problem with AFNetworking. 
I am requesting a lot of JSON data from my Server via GET using this:

```
[[SessionResponseClient sharedClient] getPath:kURIRateList parameters:@{...} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

    [_delegate receivedRateResponse:JSON];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [_delegate receivedRateResponse:nil];
}];
```

When this is called around 10-20 times, CFData seems to take most of the used memory of my app.

### Memory Usage

[image: memory used]

When I investigate both CFData and CFData (store), I get the following:

### CFData (store)

[image: CFData store memory]

### CFData

[image: CFData memory]

Side note: My app is using ARC and everything else seems to perform fine.

My question is now, as I didn't see any pending issues on AFNetworking's GitHub Page and almost no other complaints about that on the internet, **what the heck am I doing wrong?** Is anybody else facing this issue or am I the only one? Could you please post your code, as I don't think my Code looks that wrongs...

## Update 1

The code for interface:

```
@protocol RateRequestsDelegate;

@interface RateRequests : NSObject  {
   id<RateRequestsDelegate>  _delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<RateRequestsDelegate> delegate;
- (void)fetchRateList;
@end

@protocol RateRequestsDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)receivedRateResponse:(NSDictionary *)response;
@end
```

SessionResponseClient is just an extended AFHtttpClient instance, as all the AFNetworking examples demonstrate, see: [Interact with an API](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#api-client-request)

The code for receivedRateResponse:

```
- (void)receivedRateResponse:(NSDictionary *)json {
  if (!json)    {
    return;
  }

  self.moviesToInsert = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[json objectForKey:@"rated"]];

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

## Update 2

I changed the callback now to a block-based function instead of using delegates and it improved a little, but its barely mentionable and could also be caused by just a side effect of something else. How do you guys implement this? Try fetching data, display it in a table- or scrollview and then pull these data many times from the server and refresh the views

Many thanks! Paul

Comment: show us  [_delegate receivedRateResponse:JSON]; please

Comment: Is this on the device or the simulator?

Comment: and the interface of SessionResponseClient

Comment: On the device - iPad 1st generation, iOS 5.1.1.
Added the requested code...

Comment: Are you running with Zombies enabled? I've seen that cause problems with large JSON blobs.

Comment: @MishieMoo Yes, Zombies have been enabled, but even after turning them off, CFData remains the same.

Comment: Your `delegate` should be `weak`, not `strong`.  This issue may be caused by a retain cycle.

Comment: @AaronBrager tried that via unsafe_unretained, but it had no effect either...

Comment: Try switching Instruments from Statistics to Call Tree.  Enable Obj-C only and hide system calls. That may highlight the problem area.

Comment: Either way, your delegate should absolutely not be `strong`.

Comment: ...it appears to me, looking at your instruments screengrab, that nothing is leaking - there are still strong references to the data. You have a lot of *allocations*, but no leaks. Which suggests you're holding onto the data when you don't need to.

Comment: @lxt I consider that to be some kind of leak as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks dude - I had the exact same problem - your solution worked.

However, I thought I'd comment that in your solution, you're essentially turning the NSURLCache off once you receive a memory warning. I'm not sure exactly how AFNetworking uses the NSURLCache, but I'm assuming their implementation won't work as effectively if you turn it off (i.e. by setting its capacity to 0). This may slow down the request speed after your first memory warning onwards. As an extreme edge case, you might even experience unexpected behaviour after a few days of using your app, as it might not manifest until the first memory warning.

I instead suggest implementing something that removes the cached responses, but keeps the cache active:

```
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

The only issue is that AFNetworking may need to build up its cache again, but I'm assuming this won't affect the framework quite as much.

Lastly, just in case it's useful to you or anyone - in order to register your own method to a memory warning notification, you can do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self (or pointer to your singleton)
                                         selector:@selector(myMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the solution was that `CFData (store)` seems to be responsible for holding the url cache in memory when using `NSURLConnection`'s.

So all I had to do was call...

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

...to clear the cache, once I received a memory warning...

Or you can just call it whenever you want(didn't time profile that function though)...

Hope this helps someone who encounters a similar problem.

Comment: This will disable all NSURLCaching the first time around, and will have no effect on future calls except to waste more memory (unless you are creating a different NSURLCache somewhere else later.)  `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` would be more advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could give @autoreleasepool a try.
For example:

```
@autoreleasepool {

// your codes below
[[SessionResponseClient sharedClient] getPath:kURIRateList parameters:@{...} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {

    [_delegate receivedRateResponse:JSON];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [_delegate receivedRateResponse:nil];
}];
// your codes above

}
```